# Anonymous Pipe not ending stream?

Tags: c#, pipe

Hello I am having a strange error with using pipes to communicate between two process. In short everything is working fine with the program except that the client side never closes the stream, meaning the server's streamReader.readLine never returns null, causing the sever process to never terminate. I'm convinced this is a simple issue but I and struggling to find a answer. Here is some relevant code:

**Server Side:**

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(clientServer))
                    {
                        // Display the read text to the console
                        string temp;
                        int count = 0;

                        while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (count == 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("==========Parent Process found text:like==========");
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine(temp);
                            count++;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("out of while loop");

                    }
```

**Client Project:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;

class PipeClient
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        if (args.Length < 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid number of commandline arguments");
        }

        else
        {
            List<string> inputList = new List<string>();
            List<string> foundMatchList = new List<string>();

            using (PipeStream pipeClientIn =
                new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, args[0]))
            {

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClientIn))
                {
                    // Display the read text to the console
                    string temp;
                    int count = 0;
                    while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (count == 0)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("==========Client Process Read Text:==========");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(temp);
                        inputList.Add(temp);
                        count++;
                    }
                    foreach (var curtString in inputList)
                    {
                        if (curtString.Contains(args[2]))
                        {
                            foundMatchList.Add(curtString);

                        }
                    }
                }
                //Console.WriteLine("released sr");
            }
            // Console.WriteLine("released pipeClientIn");
            using (PipeStream pipeClientOut =
                new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.Out, args[1]))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClientOut))
                {

                    sw.AutoFlush = true;
                    foreach (var match in foundMatchList)
                    {

                        sw.WriteLine(match);

                    }

                }


            }
            //Console.WriteLine("released pipeClientOut");

        }


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        /* if (args.Length == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("no arguments");
        foreach(String s in args)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", s);
        }*/
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }


}
}
```

I've tested and can confirm that the client process terminates.
I attempted to manually flush and close the Client StreamWriter but this did not work.
My overall question is: Why am I never seeing the the "out of while loop" message? And how can fix my client so that it will end the stream?

Comment: Have you tried calling `sw.Flush();sw.Close();` explicitly?

Comment: Yes. It seems to make no difference.

Comment: Have you tried `while (!sr.EndOfStream) {...}` ?  ps. The client doesn't send null, it simply closes the connection, being the end of stream.

Comment: I had not until just now. However it also had no effect. And you are correct I was misinterpreting the idea that sr.readline() will return null if the stream is closed. But now it is certain that the stream is not being closed, however I do not know why. Thanks for the input I will continue to look into it

Comment: @Will: `StreamReader.ReadLine()` will in fact return `null` for the end of stream. All the client need to do is close the stream to indicate the end-of-stream; it's `ReadLine()` that translates the end-of-stream into the `null` return value.

Comment: Please provide [a minimal, complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's nothing in the tiny bit of code you posted here that would explain the behavior you describe.

Comment: Ok This is a small project so Ill just post the entire client project (Its just a main method.)

Comment: Posted, if need be I can add the whole sever project as well, its about the same size.

Answer (score 2):

Did you call **clientServer.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle()**?

[from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.anonymouspipeserverstream.disposelocalcopyofclienthandle(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The **DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle** method should be called after the
>   client handle has been passed to the client. **If this method is not
>   called, the AnonymousPipeServerStream object will not receive notice
>   when the client disposes of its PipeStream object**.

hope this helps